# VisualStudio 2010 Installer | RemovePreviousVersion behavior in Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, setup-deployment

**Installer Version 1.0.7**

- UpgradeCode = GuidXYZ
- ProductCode = GuidABC
- RemovePreviousVersions = true
- DetectNewerInstallations = false

**Installer Version 1.0.8**

- UpgradeCode = GuidXYZ
- ProductCode = GuidDEF
- RemovePreviousVersions = true
- DetectNewerInstallations = false

In Windows XP installing 1.0.8 removes 1.0.7 successfully.

In Windows 7 64 bit Professional installing 1.0.8 does not remove 1.0.7. I still see the entry in the installed Programs.

What am I missing here?

**Environment:**

- Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1
- .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do both versions use the same installation type (per-user or per-machine)? This is handled through the [ALLUSERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559%28VS.85%29.aspx) property. If the installation type is not the same, the upgrade is not performed.

You can also try creating a [log](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm) and see what happens during [FindRelatedProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368600%28VS.85%29.aspx) action.

Comment: Yes, both installations were made for all users.

Comment: How do I specify the ProductLangauge to be a valid value as listed in TemplateSummary? I saw the ProductLanguage to be 0 using Orca. How can I change it in the Visual Studio Installer project?